# Fibonacci not working in GAS assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86

after executing this code, I get an infinite loop just printing zeros :

( I have examined it closely but I still can't find out what's wrong with it )

```
.section .data
N:
 .int 35

output:
 .asciz "%f"

.section .text
.globl _start

_start:
 nop
 pushl $5
 call fibonacci

.type fibonacci, @function
fibonacci:
 pushl %ebp
 movl %esp, %ebp
 sub $8, %esp
 pushl $0
 pushl $1

.L2:
 cmpl $2, 8(%ebp)
 jg .L5
 jmp .L3

.L5:
 movl -4(%ebp), %ecx
 addl -8(%ebp), %ecx

 pushl %ecx
 pushl $output
 call printf
 movl -8(%ebp), %edx
 movl %edx,-4(%ebp)
 movl %ecx,-8(%ebp)
 jmp .L2

.L3:
 pushl $0
 call exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sub $8, %esp
pushl $0
pushl $1
```

Why the `sub`? `push` already decrements the stack pointer, so after that your local variables would be at `-12(%ebp)` and `-16(%ebp)`, not at `-4(%ebp)` and `-8(%ebp)`.

```
.L2:
 cmpl $2, 8(%ebp)
 jg .L5
 jmp .L3
```

You never decrement or do anything other than comparing against 2 your argument, so the function runs forever.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out those errors. I now fixed it but now, I get only 0 printed.

Comment: mov $2, %eax  
     .L2:  
     cmpl %eax, 8(%ebp)  
     jg .L5  
     jmp .L3

     .L5:
      (...)
      addl $1,%eax